# Get data in controller using context or create method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Which of the following is the correct, or at least the best one:

Create a method to retrieve data in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = _context.MyClass.Take(10);
    return View(list);
}
```

or use context directly:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = MyClass.MethodWrapperToGet(10);
    return View(list);
}
```

My concern with the first is that the database is too exposed; making it too easy for developers to misuse.

Comment: Depends on your implementation or how you want to separate concerns. The first is good if you're following a repository pattern and possibly using an IoC container.

Comment: Second one if you program it to an interface, would allow for easy unit testing against a mock context separate from unit testing your controller.  That's a plus I think.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the size of your project. For something small or a quick prototype I'd go with the option where controllers access the `DbContext` directly.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list = _context.MyClass.Take(10);
    return View(list);
}
```

I personally prefer separating concerts. In other words, I would create a service class that hands the controller exactly the data that it needs. Remember that the Controller should not know **how to execute tasks** but instead **what needs to be executed after what**.

This of course, does not mean you have to implement the repository pattern. Your service class could access the `DbContext` directly if you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you use a variation of exposing _context where you could pass that context through Dependency Injection so you can Unit Test your controller.

Static calls are very hard to test, at least in .Net